# Why does "cout << cout" output an address?

Tags: c++, cout, memory-address

My first understanding is that cout points to the output of terminal but I dont know if that's correct.

Maybe it is some memory address wich is not the output of the terminal but it is connected to it.

I'm confused, any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

When I do `std::cout << std::cout;` The output is `0x467f84`, which it is an address, right?

Comment: Please add a code you used to find this behaviour. Also add OS and compiler information.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf0e1f8affab64b)

Comment: Using g++, I get the behaviour described in the title, so I've added that as code; feel free to revert (it was reverted)...

Comment: Are you missing a `&`? It should be `&std::cout`. It can't work otherwise.

Comment: Im using gcc on a linux machine.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ try this http://ideone.com/McGoEe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before C++11 [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios) had a non-explicit [type conversion function to `void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to be able to use a stream as a condition.

GCC before version 5 doesn't build in C++11 mode unless using a special flag, which means that the [`operator<<` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking a `void*` will be used when outputting a stream, leading to your behavior.

If you build in C++11 mode or later, using the flag `-std=c++11`, then you should get a compiler error for that.